# Splash window does not work in mac

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, splash-screen

Due problems in showing JAVA 6 Splash screen i used following method to show a splash window.

```
File splashImageFile = new File(Constants.PATH_IMAGE + "splash.png");
        final BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(splashImageFile);
        final JWindow window = new JWindow() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -132452345234523523L;

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                Rectangle windowRect = getBounds();
                try {
                    Robot robot = new Robot(getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice());                        
                    BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(windowRect.x, windowRect.y, windowRect.width, windowRect.height));
                    g2.drawImage(capture, null, 0, 0);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                    System.out.println("Argumets mis matched.\n" + iae.getMessage());
                } catch(SecurityException se){
                    System.out.println("Security permission not supported\n" + se.getMessage());
                } catch (AWTException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Exception found when creating robot.\n" + ex.getMessage());
                }
                g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
                g2.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 15));
                g2.drawString("Loading...", 320, 260);
                g2.dispose();
            }
        };
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.repaint();
```

The image is png transparent image as i need rounded cornered rectangle shape in my window. It works on Win 7 but in mac 10.8. Mac still shows rectangle shape background. It does not seems as background either actually. Can someone tell me what may cause to that. Following are the images for each platform.

On windows

[image: windows]

On mac

[image: mac]

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Answers are great but I've seen that AWTUtilities is not always getting system support. So in some some systems answered methods may fail. Isn't there a solution much formal? I mean solution comes from the basic level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an uniform solution, you should use Java7. Per pixel translucency was nearly an "experimental" feature in Java 6, and not thought to be something you could rely on (that's why AWTUtilities was into the com.sun package, [which is not part of Java public API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)).

However, and although I haven't got a Mac to test it, I've seen people reporting that setting the frame background to Color(0, 0, 0, 0) (last parameter is the alpha channel) worked for them in MacOS. I do not remember clearly if it worked in windows (I had to use it a couple of years ago), but I've just tested it in Linux and it doesn't.

In Java 7, translucent windows are fully supported and working flawlessly in Windows, MacOS and Linux. JFrame has the new setOpacity(Alpha) method (that works only with undecorated frames) and setColor(new Color(R, G, B, Alpha)) is also working (it's equivalent, and again only working with undecorated frames).

As you can see, you can't rely on the private API AWTUtilities. In Java 6 you haven't got any "formal solution" for this problem, only hacks, private APIs and uncertainty... I don't know if it is an option, but you should think about switching to Java7 if you can.

Answer (score 6):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#shaped
This shows how to create shaped window

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            // Give the window an elliptical shape.
            // If the window is resized, the shape is recalculated here.
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                setShape(new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()));
            }
        });

        setUndecorated(true);
```

They said: As of the Java Platform, Standard Edition 6 (Java SE 6) Update 10 release, you can add translucent and shaped windows to your Swing applications.

Comment: This is not the best approach. The resulting shaped window is not antialised and the borders are jagged. This can be avoided using per pixel translucency; you could draw anything you want on the frame background, don't matter if its a png or a antialised ellipse with Java2D.

Answer (score 5):

As has already begin stated, as of Java 1.6 update 10, you have access to `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities` (a private API) which provides per pixel alphaering support.

[image]

One of the tricks to all this, is making sure you set the content pane to transparent as well.

Tested under Mac OS 10.7.5, 10.8.2; using Java 1.6.0_37 and 1.7.0_06

```
public class TestWindowTransparency {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestWindowTransparency();
    }

    public TestWindowTransparency() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                SplashWindow window = new SplashWindow();
                window.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    }

    public class SplashWindow extends JWindow {

        public SplashWindow() {

            ImageIcon icon = null;

            try {
                icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Splash02.png")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            content.setOpaque(false);
            setContentPane(content);

            JLabel lbl = new JLabel(icon);
            lbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        dispose();
                    }
                }
            });

            add(lbl);

            if (!supportsPerAlphaPixel()) {
                System.out.println("Per Pixel Alpher is not supported by you system");
            }

            setOpaque(false);

            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        }

        public boolean supportsPerAlphaPixel() {
            boolean support = false;
            try {
                Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
                support = true;
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return support;
        }

        public void setOpaque(boolean opaque) {
            try {
                Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
                if (awtUtilsClass != null) {
                    Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
                    method.invoke(null, this, opaque);
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void setOpacity(float opacity) {
            try {
                Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
                if (awtUtilsClass != null) {
                    Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpacity", Window.class, float.class);
                    method.invoke(null, this, opacity);
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public float getOpacity() {
            float opacity = 1f;
            try {
                Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
                if (awtUtilsClass != null) {
                    Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("getWindowOpacity", Window.class);
                    Object value = method.invoke(null, this);
                    if (value != null && value instanceof Float) {
                        opacity = ((Float) value).floatValue();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return opacity;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As i said using AWTUtilities may not supported by certain system and have to agree with Eneko. Also i've done this as follows. Seems somewhat similar to idea of eneko. I've tested it in windows 7 ultimate edition and apple mac os snow leopard. It worked on both. Again if this not work on linux then this also not a widely applicable solution. Wish someone can post that answer.

```
final JWindow window = new JWindow() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -132452345234523523L;

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                Rectangle windowRect = new Rectangle(getSize());
                g2.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
                g2.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Float(windowRect.x, windowRect.y, windowRect.width, windowRect.height, 85, 85));
                g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
                g2.dispose();
            }
        };            
        window.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

Comment: You've just violated the requirements of the paint chain.  You are required to call `super.paint` to ensure the component is properly painted, this is especially important when dealing with transparency.  A simpler solution would have involved replacing the content pane with you own transparent pane and using the `paintComponent` painting to it - IMHO